# Как вывести сумму из MYSQL на PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Как правильно вывести сумму всех значений на PHP? Имею такой код, но он не хочет работать.

```
<?       
   $query = DB::$the->query("SELECT sum(dAmount) FROM sel_qiwi");
   $sum = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
   echo ($sum['sum(dAmount)'])
?>
```

Вывод в index.php

```
<div class="stat-text">Всего заработано</div>
<div class="stat-digit"><?=$sum['sum(dAmount)'];?> руб.</div>
```

Ничего не выводит, пробовал даже `<div class="stat-digit"><?=$sum;?> руб.</div>`

UPD! Сделал такой запрос:

```
$allsum = DB::$the->query("SELECT SUM(dAmount) FROM `sel_qiwi` where `sStatus` = 'SUCCESS' ");
                    $allsum = $allsum->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $sum = ["sum(dAmount)"];
```

Теперь выводит "Всего заработано
Array руб." [image: Array]

Вывожу в index.php так же `<div class="stat-text">Всего заработано</div>
                                <div class="stat-digit"><?=$sum;?> руб.</div>`

Comment: Осталось узнать, что такое DB::$the->query(), и возвращает ли оно переменную типа mysql resource.

Comment: `var_dump($query)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по работающему коду, для доступа к базе данных используется PDO, а `DB::$the->query()` возвращает `PDOStatement`.

В PDO есть специальные функции для получения различных типов результатов. В данном случае надо использовать [PDOStatement::fetchColumn()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn):

```
$stmt = DB::$the->query("SELECT SUM(dAmount) FROM `sel_qiwi` where `sStatus` = 'SUCCESS'");
$sum = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень мне помогли! Все работает.